# Kubernetes application deployment - Helm and Operators

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, gitops

I want to deploy a microservices application with multiple microservices and two operators for external applications.

The microservices are consolidated under the helm chart. The external stateful applications like Cassandra DB and Kafka have an operator.

How do I combine and manage the lifecycle of the entire stack? What's the recommended way to do this deployment?

Thanks
Guru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helm-based operator which can be scaffolded out using an existing helm chart. https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/helm/

Comment: I need to deploy both helm charts and operators. How do I do that?

Comment: If you use operator-sdk to scaffold a lightweight helm-based operator from the existing helm charts, then you are dealing with only operators, which means that you'll be able to deploy everything using kubernetes custom resources.

Comment: Thanks. How do I deploy multiple operators? Can I use Operator Lifecycle manager or any other tool to deploy operators or orchestrate the deployment of other operators from the main orchestrating operator by writing custom code?

Comment: Yes, OLM can help here. For complex situations,  some folks also create another operator that acts as a wrapper. Admin manages it with a single CR, and when the wrapper operator reconciles it creates the CRs that trigger other operators.